# Is there any way to add "Relationship Type" to a membership type that already has members?

Tags: civimember

We've decided that the way we initially setup civimemberships for our organization does not meet our needs. We need to extend membership to employees of member organizations so that employees will receive email communications sent to member organizations.

CiviCRM does not allow this setting to be changed through the UI. It is something I can change through the database?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would have to change the civicrm_membership_type table, in columns relationship_type_id and relationship_direction. Be careful though as these are multi-valued field, so if you inherit the membership based on multiple relationship types you will need to store CONCAT_WS(X'01', {type_1}, {type_2});

Comment: Note that the already created membership won't inherit magically after you've updated the database so you will need to update them, either using the UI or the API.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since this question was asked but there is now an extension to help with this: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/membershiprelationshiptypeeditor